# Yum command on new EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

What's the recommended method to automatically run 'yum update' after a new EC2 Instance launch (Instance based on Amazon Linux AMI)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [CloudInit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) User-Data Script.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally configure a shell script to pass as user data, which would run all needed server set up tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Configure an init task on a fresh EC2 instance to run `yum update` on some sort of schedule (you generally want to ensure that all of your instances are always running identical versions of software), then create a new AMI from the running instance you just modified.

From then-on, simply launch your new AMI instead of a fresh AMI. Over time, you'll want to do this same thing again so that instance launches won't take so long as more and more updates become available.

Once every 3-4 months seems to be a good delta.